# Populating a DataTable with JSON, need to render a hyperlink in one column with a value found in a different JSON field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, twitter-bootstrap

I have a sample json object with data:

```
[ 
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Fred",
        "author": "Flintstone"
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "Fred",
        "author": "Flintstone"
    }, {
        "id": 3,
        "title": "Fred",
        "author": "Flintstone"
    }.....
```

HTML

```
<table class="table" id="tblRunbook">
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th width="60px">ID</th>
                                                    <th width="300px">Title</th>
                                                    <th width="200px">Author</th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>

                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
```

JavaScript:

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#tblRunbook').dataTable({
            <!-- Retrieve a static json file, you could also have a URL to a controller method. -->
            "sAjaxSource" : "/getRunbooks",
            "sAjaxDataProp": "",
            <!-- Indicate to dataTable what the field names are we want, in the order we want them in the table. -->
            "aoColumns": [
                          {"data": "id"},
                          {"data": "title",
                             "render": function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
                                return '<a href="runbook?rbID=" + data.id + '>' + data + '</a>';}
                          },
                          {"data": "author"}
                ]


        });
    });
```

The column with `ID` will be hidden, but I want to make the link `runbook?rbID = ID`. I would like to access the previous field in the JSON object, in this case, `"data" : "id"` and set it inside the second field where the function returns `'<a href="runbook?rbID=" + data.id + '>'`, where `data.id` is the `ID`.

Comment: You can use jQuery map to create new datasource, from unlimited other datasources, and use the new model for the datatable. Datatables can only work with one source. But if its allot of data it may be slow, so redoing the model on the server might be a better idea.

Comment: I think this http://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/200/getting-values-from-hidden-column-rows would help to solve.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a work-around.

```
var runbookID;



        "aoColumns": [
                      {"data": function(data, type, row, meta){
                          runbookID = data.id;
                          return data.id;}
                      },
                      {"data": "title",
                         "render": function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
                            return "<a href='runbook?rbID=" + runbookID + "'>" + data + '</a>';}
                      },
                      {"data": "author"}
            ]
```

Comment: I had the same question, and this does indeed work. But it can't be the best way to craft a link from two json fields. Curious if you've learned another way to do it since? Thanks!